# Read an XML node

Tags: c++, xml, xmlnode

Hi well I'm coding a C++ .DLL, and I want to know if it's possible to read an XML node with it.
The XML file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<XML>
    <VIDEO>
        <FULLSCREEN>TRUE</FULLSCREEN>
    </VIDEO>

</XML>
```

I want to make the dll check if the "FULLSCREEN" node is true before do anything, like make appear a messagebox if the value is true and do nothing if the value is false.
Hope someone can bring some help, thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using an XML parser? If so, which one? If not, why not?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is, have a look for an XML library e.g. Xerces.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming windows (implied since you mentioned dll), then use the msxml library API built into windows.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms759192(v=VS.85).aspx

Comment: Could you please put an example of it? I really don't know/understand how to use msxml :C.

Comment: @Derezzed: the page linked to by selbie *is* a list of examples.  For instance, clicking on "Load an XML DOM object from a file (C/C++)" and then "Source: loadDOM.cpp" will lead you to [a full program listing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms765465(v=VS.85).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PugiXml](http://code.google.com/p/pugixml/).
It is very convinient IMHO.